# How do I prevent re-declaring a variable in a react component when it renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, variable-declaration

I have a React component called Flightlist, which receives an object from its parent component via props.newFlight.

I would like to push each object received from the parent to a local array, called flightList.

The problem I have is that I declare this array as an empty array at the beginning of my component, and every time that the component re-renders, the array that I pushed to, is re-declared as an empty array.

Hence, when I log the array to the console after the push() method, it always only contains the latest object received via props.

Please see my FlightList component below:

```
import Card from '../UI/Card';

const FlightList = (props) => {
  let flightList = [];

  flightList.push(props.newFlight);

  console.log('flightlist array', flightList);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Card>
            <h1></h1>
          </Card>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default FlightList;
```

(Note: The parent component is the one that manages the state, hence I am not managing state in the child component)

How can I declare this array in the child component without having it re-declared every time the state updates?

Comment: Use state for persistence then. React's re-render will re-initialize all variables from fresh. State is the only way it keeps track of a persistent value b/w re-renders.

Comment: Use state or ref

Comment: Why not just move `let flightList = [];` outside the component? Hard to advise without fully understanding the context. Specifically what it is that you ultimately do with `flightList`.

Comment: @codemonkey multiple instances of the same component would share this array then

Answer (score 0):

If the parent component is responsible for managing the state, then instead of passing an individual `newFlight` variable to `FlightList`, you should declare the `flightList` variable in the parent component using `useState` and then pass that as a prop to the `FlightList` component:

Parent component:

```
const [flightList, setFlightList] = useState([])

// When a new flight is added
const addNewFlight = (newFlight) => {
setFlightList([...flightList, newFlight])
}

return <FlightList flightList={flightList} />
```

Your `FlightList` component:

```
import Card from '../UI/Card';

const FlightList = (props) => {
  console.log(props.flightList)

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Card>
            <h1></h1>
          </Card>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default FlightList;
```